# Bidirectional selection sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm working on a program to sort a small array. This is a class assignment and required a selection sort, but I wanted to go a little further than it requested. I've done selection sorts before, and I wanted to try to implement a bidirectional version. It works, save for one problem. My second result is always the second result, and is never sorted. I feel like I'm missing something small and stupid.

Here's the code for my search function

```
void biSelSort(string engine[], double hits[]) {    
    int k = ARRAY_SIZE - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        int min = i;
        int max = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= k; j++) {
            if (hits[j] < hits[min]) {
                min = j;
            }
            if (hits[j] > hits[max]) {
                max = j;
            }
        }
        string tS = engine[min];
        double tD = hits[min];
        engine[min] = engine[i];
        hits[min] = hits[i];
        engine[i] = tS;
        hits[i] = tD;

        if (max == i) {
            tS = engine[min];
            tD = hits[min];
            engine[min] = engine[k];
            hits[min] = hits[k];
            engine[k] = tS;
            hits[k] = tD;
        } else {
            tS = engine[max];
            tD = hits[max];
            engine[max] = engine[k];
            hits[max] = hits[k];
            engine[k] = tS;
            hits[k] = tD;
        }
        i++;
        k--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second result is your second result?  That makes sense I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean to increment i twice, once in your for statement, once at the end of your loop? If you did, you really should modify your code so you're only doing it in one place.

Comment: Wow. I knew it was stupid, but I didn't know it was that stupid. I started with a while loop, then switched to a for loop when I looked back the next morning. Thanks for the code review.